# 3 Become 1: Merging [dad] and [fatherhood] with [father]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms

First of all, [father](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/father) is now [present](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/father) and, especially good news for the adherents of more traditional values, [father](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/father) is [Master](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms).

There are, at the time of writing, still 11 questions tagged [dad](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dad) and 11 questions tagged [fatherhood](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fatherhood). The next step is to [merge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70718/377968) these tags, so that all questions are tagged [father](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/father).

Now, all 24 questions with one of the tags are [displayed together](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/father).

Having had a look at all questions tagged either [dad](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dad) or [fatherhood](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fatherhood), I see no issues with a merge. [father](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/father) seems like a perfect replacement. However, I might have missed something, so if you find a question among them that makes you disagree, please share your concerns.

**Shall we merge [dad](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dad) and [fatherhood](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fatherhood) with [father](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/father)?**

Comment: "...and, especially good news for the adherents of more traditional values, father is Master."  Good one!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the past thread, this makes sense.

Merged as requested.